# How to set multiple elements style via getBoundingClientRect()

Tags: javascript, getboundingclientrect

I am trying to set elements (children of a container with `transform`) to fixed position relative to the viewport. I'm attempting to find each of them, and assign to a variable via `getBoundingClientRect()`, then define style properties from that variable.

```html
<div>
  <div class="preview-container">
    <div>
      <!-- Image -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="preview-container">
    <div>
      <!-- Image -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- more -->
```

**JS v1**

```js
$('.preview-container').each(function(el) {
  preview = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(preview);
  preview.style.position = "fixed";
  preview.style.top = "0";
  preview.style.left = "0";
});
```

This works without the three `style` lines and `console` displays all of the `.preview-container` elements correctly. Adding the `style` lines produces errors about those `style` properties not being defined:

- `jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'position')`
- `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'position')`

I don't understand that because `preview` is working in `console`.

**JS v2**

This attempt works as is, but is less complete. `console` is producing all of the `.preview-container` elements, but I haven't been able to incorporate `getBoundingClientRect()`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".preview-container").forEach(preview => {
  preview.style.position = "fixed";
  preview.style.top = "0";
  preview.style.left = "0";
  console.log(preview);
});
```

I feel like I am closer with JS v1, and am missing something simple with the `style` properties. How should I proceed?

Comment: Could I ask you to edit the snippets I created from your code to ensure that they adequately represent your code? Click [edit] just below your question, scroll through the preview below the textarea and click on the "edit the above snippet" link (yes, it should probably be a <button> instead, but here we are).

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect` returns an object with position and dimension properties. It is not a DOM element and doesn't have styling. Attempting to style it would be like trying to color a line using an object describing its slope and a point on it. Rethinking is needed: _getBoundingClientRect doesn't have anything to do with element style._

Comment: **JS v2** appears to be what you need. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: My understanding is that `getBoundingClientRect()` makes it possible to set an element's position to `fixed` relative the viewport which is what I need. JS v2 does this relative to their immediate parent.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the interfaces for [**DOMRect**](https://drafts.fxtf.org/geometry/#DOMRect) (there are several), it states that updating properties of a `DOMRect` updates the position of the element it was called on, as in this example:

```js
"use strict";
$('.preview-container').each(function(el) {
  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  this.style.position = "fixed";
  // this.style.top = "0";
  rect.x = 0;
  // this.style.left = "0";
  rect.y = 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- body-html -->
<div>
  <div class="preview-container">
    <div>
      Image 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="preview-container">
    <div>
      Image 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note

- `this` has been used to refer to preview divisions in the `each` argument function, not `el`.
- Changes to position are made by setting properties of `rect`, not `style`, as allowed in the standard, but this is uncommon.
- Usually positions are set either in CSS, or using element `style` objects (the `this.style` lines commented out above), without calling `getBoundingClientRect` to obtain a `DOMRect` first.

However when an element descends from an element with a `transform` property, the [`transform` element behaves as the containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for `fixed` elements below as shown here:

```js
$('.preview-container').each(function(el) {
  this.style.position = "fixed";
  this.style.top = "0";
  this.style.left = "0";
});
```

```css
/* CSS from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform */

div.ancestor {  
  border: solid red;
  transform: translate(30px, 20px) rotate(20deg);
  width: 140px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- body-html -->

<div class="ancestor">
  <div class="preview-container">
    <div>
      Image 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ancestor">
  <div class="preview-container">
    <div>
      Image 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to fix preview container positioning relative to the view port, try moving them out from under the `transform` ancestor by, say, appending them to the `body` element. If aspects of the transform operation need to be retained on moved preview containers, a suitable CSS transform would need to be separately applied to them after the move.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the name of your variables, in the first one you call it el and you refer as preview. And to get the values of getBoundingClientRect you need to create another variable.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".preview-container").forEach(preview => {
previewValues = preview.getBoundingClientRect();
  preview.style.position = "fixed";
  preview.style.top = "0";
  preview.style.left = "0";
  console.log(preview);
  console.log(previewValues);}

)
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="preview-container">
    <div>
      <!-- Image -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="preview-container">
    <div>
      <!-- Image -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- more -->
```

Comment: And also you are not using getBoundingClientRect so, you don't need to event create that variable at all.

Comment: Hey - I am trying to incorporate `getBoundingClientRect` though because I thought that was what made it possible to work with the element relative to the viewport. The `.preview-container`s are children of a higher container that has a `transform` and being `fixed` was then relative to that parent (i.e. how `transform` sets a new set of coordinates). What you have doesn't use the variable you said I can omit so it's the same that I have above in JS v2.